# Join table is not inserted by JPA

Tags: angularjs, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have three tables (user/role/user_role) related to each other by pk and fk ,User entity has a set of roles and there is a join table named user_role.
I have created a page by angularjs to create a new user which you can select the role for the user as well,after form submition user table and user_role table needs to be inserted but i am getting below error.

#### AngularJS :

```
<div class="row"> 
<div class="form-group col-md-12"> 
<label class="col-md-2 control-lable">Role</label> 
<div class="col-md-7"> 
<select ng-model="user.roles"> 
<option value="">--Select--</option> 
<option value="1">USER</option>
<option value="2">ADMIN</option> 
</select> 
</div> 
</div> 
</div>
```

#### User :

```
@Entity
public class User {

private long id;
private String password;
private String username;
private String address;
private String email;
private Boolean enabled;
private Set<Role> roles;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "password", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "username", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "address", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 45)
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = true)
public Boolean getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(Boolean enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    User user = (User) o;

    if (id != user.id) return false;
    if (password != null ? !password.equals(user.password) : user.password != null) return false;
    if (username != null ? !username.equals(user.username) : user.username != null) return false;
    if (address != null ? !address.equals(user.address) : user.address != null) return false;
    if (email != null ? !email.equals(user.email) : user.email != null) return false;
    if (enabled != null ? !enabled.equals(user.enabled) : user.enabled != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (password != null ? password.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (username != null ? username.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (address != null ? address.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (email != null ? email.hashCode() : 0);
    result = 31 * result + (enabled != null ? enabled.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}

@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_role",schema = "LoginMaster",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false))
public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
}
```

#### Role :

```
@Entity
public class Role {

private long id;
private String name;
private Set<User> users;

@Id
@Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Basic
@Column(name = "name", nullable = true, length = 255)
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Role role = (Role) o;

    if (id != role.id) return false;
    if (name != null ? !name.equals(role.name) : role.name != null) return false;

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
    result = 31 * result + (name != null ? name.hashCode() : 0);
    return result;
}


@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}
}
```

#### Rest Service :

```
  @PostMapping(value ="/",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public ResponseEntity<User>createUser(@Valid @RequestBody final      User user) {

 logger.info("Creating User : {}", user);

 if (userJpaRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername()) != null) {
 logger.error("Unable to create. A User with name {} already exist",        user.getUsername());
 return new ResponseEntity<User>(new CustomErrorType("Unable to      create new user. A User with name " + user.getUsername() + " already     exist."),HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    userJpaRepository.save(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

#### Request :

```
   {"username":"test2","password":"test2","address":"teaddress","email":"test2@gmail.com","roles":"1"}
```

#### Error :

```
 {"timestamp":"2019-07-    24T09:50:15.672+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON    parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of    VALUE_STRING token; nested exception is    com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.HashSet` out of VALUE_STRING token\n
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON ,the `roles` attribute is not sent as an array but as as single attribute, so this attribute cannot be deserialized into a HashSet.
If you have a ManyToMany relation, I guess your `select` should be `multiple` in order to assign a list of roles and not only a single role :

```html
<select multiple ng-model="user.roles">
```

Comment: You're right but how to send it as an array as only a single role is going to be selected for the new user.

Comment: If you want to keep a ```select``` with a unique choice, you must not bind ```user.roles``` to your component.  Declare and bind another variable and push it into ```user.roles``` on angular side before calling your service

Answer (score 0):

It should accept single value as Array too.

**use this in your code for SET<>:**

```
 @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
```

Comment: I did it as you said and now getting a new error {"timestamp":"2019-07-24T15:57:56.753+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.avasys.angularboot.model.Role` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('1'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: \n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); ] (through reference chain: com.avasys.angularboot.model.User[\"roles\"]->java.lang.Object[0])","path":"/api/user/"}

Comment: This error is not related to your previous problem. It is causing due to different problem...

Comment: I recommend, check your getter setter and Constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the way of sending roles as an array
 and put below annotations on top of getter
 method and program moved one step forward.

```
  @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
  @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "user_role",schema = "LoginMaster",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id",
        referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false))
    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
    }
```